# Should extra layers be added just to support __repr__?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am working on a Python project that mainly returns closures instead of the traditional class-based approach. For example:

```
def term(token):
    def fn(text):
        return (...)
    return fn
```

As you can imagine, debugging and testing closures are a nightmare especially if I use the same name for the closure throughout my code. For example:

```
>>> term('t')
<function fn at 0x...>
```

So I tried wrapping it in a class to get the special `__repr__` handling from a namedtuple:

```
def rr(cls, attrs):
    T = namedtuple(cls, attrs)

    class G(object):
        __slots__ = ()

        def __init__(self, repr_message, callable):
            self.callable = callable
            self.repr_message = repr_message

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.callable(*args, **kwargs)

        def __repr__(self):
            return self.repr_message

    K = type(cls, (G,), {})

    def wrapper(fn):
        def init(*args, **kwargs):
            t = T(*args, **kwargs)
            return K(
                repr(t),
                fn(*args, **kwargs),
            )
        return init
    return wrapper
```

Such that:

```
>>> rr('Term', ['token'])(term)('$')
Term(token='$')
```

As you can imagine this takes probably a hit on performance. My question is if this kind of wrapping is preferrable, if at all more Pythonic than just returning the "ugly" closure?

Comment: Your problem is a Python **2** problem; in Python 3 the `repr` of a closure reports the defining environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lighter approach is to simply modify the closure's `func_name` attribute. The result isn't as pretty as what your code produces, but it will have minimal impact on RAM and performance.

```
def term(token):
    def fn(text):
        return text.split(token)
    fn.func_name = "term(token={0!r})".format(token)
    return fn

s = 'splitthistestup'
f = term('t')
g = term('i')
print(f, f(s))
print(g, g(s))
```

**typical output**

```
<function term(token='t') at 0xb74878b4> ['spli', '', 'his', 'es', 'up']
<function term(token='i') at 0xb74878ec> ['spl', 'tth', 'stestup']
```

For Python 3 you need to do something slightly different.

```
fn.func_name = ...
```

becomes:

```
fn.__qualname__ = ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I understood from your question that you were still using Python 2.

In Python 3 (3.3+ as we're using `inspect.getclosurevars`) here one can do some serious magic to do an almost-no-overhead decorator that will (for this case) produce the desired output; this is harder to do in Python 2, since Python 2 functions do not know their fully-qualified name:

```
import inspect

class reprcorate(object):
    __slots__ = ('__call__',)

    def __init__(self, callable):
        self.__call__ = callable

    def __repr__(self):
        func = self.__call__
        funcname = func.__qualname__
        funcname = funcname.replace('.<locals>', '')

        try:
            closure_vars = inspect.getclosurevars(func)
            args = '(%s)' % ', '.join('%s=%r' % i for i in closure_vars.nonlocals.items())
            last_part = '.' + func.__name__

            if funcname.endswith(last_part):
                funcname = funcname[:-len(last_part)]

        except:
            args = '(...)'

        return funcname + args

def term(token):
    @reprcorate
    def fn(text):
        @reprcorate
        def fn2(fn2arg):
            print(token, text, fn2arg)

        return fn2

    return fn

print(term('foo'))
print(term('foo')('bar'))
```

prints out

```
term(token='foo')
term.fn(token='foo', text='bar')
```

---

How this works is that the `__call__` can be assigned for an *instance*; so we do not need to have a dummy `__call__` trampoline; we also use the `__slots__` to decrease runtime overhead.

The real magic lies in the `__repr__` method, wherein the function/closure that was decorated is carefully dissected. The free variables that the function uses from the outer scope can be inspected with the help of [`inspect.getclosurevars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getclosurevars) which returns a named tuple; we're especially interested in the `nonlocals` since these are the values used from the outer scopes; this is a simple dictionary of variable name to value. We make this into a nice string of `variable=value, variable=value`. These are not strictly the function arguments, but are the values that are seen and used in the inner closure.

We also clean the function name a bit; in Python 3 the name of the function is in `__name__`, and the fully qualified name is in `__qualname__`; the `__qualname__` for closures looks like `foo.<locals>.bar.<locals>.baz`, so we remove all `.<locals>`, to get `foo.bar.baz`; we then remove the last dotted part if it matches the `__funcname__` of our wrapped function, and append the nicely formatted arguments at the end, for truly nice results.

Comment: Thanks - this is really good and I would've used it if I didn't need to support both versions of Python. From my understanding, aren't "magic-methods" ignored on a per-object basis, instead only acknowledged if the object's class has the magic-method?